# Как сделать шаблонное добавление "блока" (поста)

Tags: javascript, html, оптимизация, оптимизация-сайтов

Скажите пожалуйста, как сделать добавление, заранее описанного "блока" (поста) одной командой, ориентируясь на сегодняшний этикет?

Исходный код:

```
var newpost = document.createElement("div");
newpost.className = "panel panel-default";
var newpost_header = document.createElement("div");
newpost_header.className = "panel-heading";
var newpost_header_h3 = document.createElement("h3");
newpost_header_h3.className = "panel-title";
newpost_header_h3.innerHTML = item.Title;
var newpost_body = document.createElement("div");
newpost_body.className = "panel-body";

if (shortPost.length < 300) {
    newpost_body.innerHTML = shortPost;
} else {
    newpost_body.innerHTML = shortPost.substr(0, 300) + "...";
}

var newpost_btn = document.createElement("button");
newpost_btn.className = "btn";
newpost_btn.innerHTML = "Открыть";
newpost_btn.onclick = function(event) {
    var number = event.target.id.replace("post_", "")
    document.getElementById('Content').innerHTML = DataPost.Reference[parseInt(number)].Content;
    myFunction();
};

newpost_btn.type = "button";
newpost_btn.id = "post_" + i;

newpost.appendChild(newpost_header);
newpost_header.appendChild(newpost_header_h3);
newpost.appendChild(newpost_body);
newpost.appendChild(newpost_btn);
document.getElementById("Posts").appendChild(newpost);
```

То-что это можно вынести в отдельную функцию я знаю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из подходов это просто задать элемент через интерполируемую строчку.

```
var class1 = isBig ? "big" : "small";
var html = `<div><ul class="${class1}">
           // разметка
           </ul></div>`;
```

Плюс этого подхода в том что вся html разметка видна сразу.

Так же есть библиотеки шаблонизаторы, но я ими не пользуюсь, поэтому не могу подсказать названия. Сам использую React, на нём вся структура основана на компонентах, и там всё это очень красиво из коробки. Но react используется целиком для одностраничных приложений, если всё приложение классическое то для одной страницы думаю react не стоит использовать, есть что-то полегче.

Comment: lzk интерполяционных строк "+" не обязателен

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ого, класс, спасибо, не знал.

Comment: `var class1 = isBig ? "big" : "small";` а что это?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy это пример как вставлять вычисляемые блоки внутрь шаблона. В данном случае есть `isBig == true` тогда делаем один класс, а если другой то другой.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин `ого, класс, спасибо, не знал`... еще можно писать интерполяцию внутри интерполяции)) http://jsraccoon.ru/es6-interpolation  .... про многострочные уже не помню где читал.. наверное тут: https://web.archive.org/web/20170704163611/http://css-live.ru:80/articles/es6-literaly-shablona-iznutri.html  ... кстати прикольная статья о 350 фичах es6 https://web.archive.org/web/20170629190321/http://css-live.ru/articles/obzor-es6-v-350-punktax.html  ...